# More than one join MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
**Sub Menu**
id|title
1 | Sub A

**Root_Sub**
id|root_id|sub_id
1 |9      |1


**Root Menu**
id|title
9 | Root X
```

I need to find out the id of a sub menu's root menu.

To do this I use:

```
SELECT * FROM sub_menu LEFT JOIN root_sub ON sub_menu.id = root_sub.sub_id
```

This gives me '9' as the ID.

But I also need to get the root menu's title, ie getting the title 'Root X'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM sub_menu
LEFT JOIN root_sub ON sub_menu.id = root_sub.sub_id
LEFT JOIN root_menu ON root_sub.root_id = root_menu.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.ID AS subID,
        a.title AS SubTitle,
        c.ID AS RootID,
        c.Title as RootTitle
FROM    sub_Menu a
        INNER JOIN root_sub b
            On a.ID = b.sub_ID
        INNER JOIn root_Menu c
            ON b.root_ID = c.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ccff/4)

If all records have atleast one match on the other tables, an `INNER JOIN` is much preferred but if one is *nullable*, change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`